# Counting Unique Rows In A Table After Filtering Rows

Tags: excel

I have asked a number of people to complete an online test, and I registered their IP addresses when they connected to the test page. Now, using excel, I want to count if there have been entries from multiple IP addresses with the same user ID.

[image: See here the example tables.]

In the Page Loadings part, I have very long list of user IDs and the IP Addresses they have connected from. I want to list the occurrences like on the right. User with ID 1 connected from only one IP Address, "A". So, I have 1 next to that ID. User 3 had 2 different IPs "C" and "D", so I see a 2 next to that ID on the right.

I could not figure out a way to do this. I'd appreciate some help!

Note: I want to avoid using VBA, if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following array formula

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$19=D3,IF($B$2:$B$19<>"",MATCH("~"&$B$2:$B$19,$B$2:$B$19&"",0))),ROW($B$2:$B$19)-ROW($B$2)+1),1))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]